# Deleting from an Array using object

Tags: java

If you have an array ( cannot be `ArrayList` ) that will be used to store specific things such as "dog type", "dog name" and "dog age". Then you create an object that will obviously input these elements. However, if the user wants to remove the whole object ( so all inputs name, age and age ) then they can do this by just deleting the age of the dog then all will be removed. Would this be possible without using an ArrayList ?

Comment: The array element can be changed so that it has a vale of `null`, but you can't change the *length* of an array after creation.

Comment: I'm talking hypothetically @KamleshArya because it's something I want to implement in my new learning curve project = ) was just intrigued as to whether this would be possible to use

Comment: The array contains the `Dog` objects right? Because this statement of yours *If you have an array ( cannot be ArrayList ) that will be used to store specific things such as "dog type", "dog name" and "dog age".* is quite confusing.

Comment: You either store dogs or dogs' properties

Comment: Yeah, so for example : You have two objects both with the same parameters/elements "DOG TYPE", "DOG NAME" and "DOG AGE". For number 1 object we want to keep this data, so we leave it as it is. However, we've decided we don't want our dog data anymore for object 2... so we remove this by removing dog age @Ɍ.Ɉ

Comment: You could use *array of tuples* for the same. Then when deleting, you can refer the object by the dog_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way. It is no really good Java approach, but it works and you can easily refactor it.

Here you have got Dog class:

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Dog[] removeByName(Dog[] list, String name) {
        int counter = 0;
        Dog[] result = new Dog[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (!list[i].getName().equals(name)) {
                result[counter] = list[i];
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Here you can see how to use it:

```
public class NotArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog[] dogs = new Dog[3];

        Dog d1 = new Dog();
        d1.setName("aaa");
        d1.setAge(1);

        Dog d2 = new Dog();
        d2.setName("bbb");
        d2.setAge(1);

        Dog d3 = new Dog();
        d3.setName("ccc");
        d3.setAge(1);

        dogs[0] = d1;
        dogs[1] = d2;
        dogs[2] = d3;

        Dog[] res = Dog.removeByName(dogs, "aaa");
        for (Dog d : res) {
            if (d != null)
                System.out.println(d.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then I guess you can have a delete method which removes a `Dog` object reference from the array by making that particular index as `null`.

```
public void removeDog(Dog[] dogArray, int age) {
    for(int i = 0; i < dogArray.length; i++) {
        if(dogArray[i].getAge() == age){
           dogArray[i] = null; // removing the dog object by making it null
           break; 
        }
    }
}
```

You need to note that the following are the assumptions made for the above method.

- The size of the array doesn't change. Just that the index which referenced the now deleted `Dog` object is now `null`.
- If there are multiple `Dog` objects with the same age, the `Dog` object present in the array first(index-wise) would be removed.
- The `dogArray` parameter is passed in case it is not an instance variable, else, it can be avoided.
- Age is of the type `int` and that the `Dog` class has a public getter for it, `getAge()`.
- This method doesn't return anything, but you can make it return a `boolean`(deletion status) or `Dog`(deleted Dog object) depending on your needs.